# Track Incomming Traffic

Tags: apache2, mysql, dictionary

I am using a local server and I am using a puclic static IP to access my software. My question is, is there any way to track which IP or which device is trying to access my software or hitting my ip? If yes, can I have a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tcpdump` command to track incoming traffic on any interface, on SSL port 443.

```
sudo tcpdump -ni any port 443 -Qin
```

To track incoming traffic on any port:

```
sudo tcpdump -ni any -Qin
```